# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()

Tags: laravel-8, service-provider

when I try to run composer update this error will appear

```
In app.php line 158:

  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::defaultProviders()


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I tried adding this use

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

but still error